# Cómo sacar el valor máximo de una agrupación con python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Estoy practicando con el fichero de netflix shows. https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows

Pretendo mostrar el año en el que más películas se han realizado.
Agrupo por año y obtengo el máximo, los 744 pero debería mostrar que se dan en el año 2017, sin embargo, obtengo el máximo año disponible en el dataset, que es el 2021.
¿Cómo podría quedarme con esa línea 67 para recuperar así el 2017 que es donde se da el máximo que busco?

Mi código:

```
print ('Maximo en peliculas')
movies= nfx.loc[(nfx.type=='Movie')]
movies.groupby(['release_year'], as_index=False).size()

print(movies.groupby(['release_year'], as_index=False).size())
print(movies.groupby(['release_year'], as_index=False).size().max())
```

Mi resultado:

```
Max. movies in year
    release_year  size
0           1942     2
1           1943     3
2           1944     3
3           1945     3
4           1946     1
..           ...   ...
67          2017   744
68          2018   734
69          2019   582
70          2020   411
71          2021    12

[72 rows x 2 columns]
release_year    2021
size             744
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Buen día, antes de la respuesta, recuerda que si no ingresas la información completa es muy difícil ayudarte, ya que requiere que invirtamos más tiempo en hacerlo. En otra de tus preguntas te comenté  que hacía falta la información de tu `dataframe` aquí hace falta también. Por suerte para ti aún tengo el ejemplo que hice en tu pregunta pasada así que ya sabía la estructura de tu `dataframe` pero no siempre la misma persona va a responder todas tus preguntas por lo que ingresar la información completa es necesario

Comment: @HeytalePazguato disculpa, conseguí encontrar el dataframe pensando que serviría de ayuda y no tendría los problemas de la pregunta anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo primero que puedes hacer es guardar la nueva agrupación que haz hecho en un `dataframe`

```
df2 = movies.groupby(['release_year'], as_index=False).size()
```

Luego puedes utilizar el método `idxmax()` para obtener el id de la fila que tenga mayor valor en la columna que elijas, en este caso es `size` de `df2`

```
df2['size'].idxmax()
```

**Edición:**

Si quieres obtener toda la fila con datos puedes aplicar el resultado de `idxmax()` a `df2`

```
df2.iloc[df2['size'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: Con la edicion si, mil gracias!